# Junit failures related to cobertura with multi-module maven project in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am getting below test failures when building the multi-module maven project in `jenkins`.

```
JDK version - 1.8.51
junit - 4.12
org.codehaus.mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin - 2.7
powermock-easymock-release-full - 1.6.2
net.sourceforge.cobertura / cobertura - 2.1.1
```

All the above are latest plugins.

**Test failures**

**Error 1**

```
Error Message
net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector.registerClass(Ljava/lang/String;)V
Stacktrace
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector.registerClass(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

**Error 2**

```
Error Message
Could not initialize class com.test.it.logging.EventLogHandler
Stacktrace
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.test.it.logging.EventLogHandler
```

**Error 3**

```
Error Message
Failed to transform class with name com.test.it.ra.ReportArchiveConfProvider. Reason: cannot find net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.LightClassmapListener
Stacktrace
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.test.it.ra.ReportArchiveConfProvider. Reason: cannot find net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.LightClassmapListener
at 
org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:266)
```

JFYI that it was working fine with JDK 7 and old version plugins. Have anyone faced this issue ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not on the same configurations as you, but ran into the same error around LightClassmapListener.  I got past the issue by clearing my workspace.

In the jenkins job; click the workspace and select 'Wipe out Current Workspace'